# SOLR - Tika - Store binary version of file

Tags: solr, apache-tika

I am using Tika integrated in SOLR to index documents and allow search on said documents. This works pretty smoothly (right now my setup is exactly the same as the example as the example that ships with SOLR) and I can indeed index and search documents. As well as indexing the document I would like to store the binary version in SOLR so that when a search returns a result I can return a full PDF/Word/etc. document for download. Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope.
Solr is full Text search engine and does not provide any out of the box implementation for storing the binary files.
Instead, you can easily host the binary files outside and have them rendered through http linked through id.